# Repartition by multiple columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to repartition and save my dataframe which contains around 20 million records into multiple CSV files.

`df.repartition('col1','col2','col3').write.csv(path)`

I would like to save it into as many CSV files are there are unique combinations of `('col1', 'col2', 'col3')`, which sometimes can be around 4000.

Approaches I tried:

1. I tried setting the shuffle partition value to 4000 explicitly

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 4000)`

2. Tried to perform group by and set the partition no as the number of groups.

`partitioned = final_df.groupBy('col1','col2','col3').count()`

`partition_no = partitioned.count()`

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 4000)`

Both the approaches yielded the same result. The number of files was less than the number of partitions. How can I ensure that the no. of CSV files saved is the same as the no. of partitions?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using coalesce(4000) on your write operation ?

Comment: @KSNidhin Do you mean repartition by the three columns and then use coalesce?

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay for the csv to partitioned on disk, this works:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(x, x + 1, x - 1, "a") for x in range(1, 4)], ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
)

df.show()
```

```
+----+----+----+----+                                                           
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   0|   a|
|   2|   3|   1|   a|
|   3|   4|   2|   a|
+----+----+----+----+
```

```py
df.repartition("col1", "col2", "col3").write.partitionBy("col1", "col2", "col3").csv(
    "test.csv", mode="overwrite"
)
```

It will yield a csv on disk like this:

```
.
├── _SUCCESS
├── col1=1
│   └── col2=2
│       └── col3=0
│           └── part-00001-76768c63-d6a6-4d8c-b5a2-8c0f4131d825.c000.csv
├── col1=2
│   └── col2=3
│       └── col3=1
│           └── part-00002-76768c63-d6a6-4d8c-b5a2-8c0f4131d825.c000.csv
└── col1=3
    └── col2=4
        └── col3=2
            └── part-00000-76768c63-d6a6-4d8c-b5a2-8c0f4131d825.c000.csv
```

However, it's typically not ideal to have nested directories like this. Another option is to create a new column that is the concatenation of col1-col3, then use `repartition` and `partitionBy` on that new column. It will flatten the directory structure listed above.